# Swift 2 Xcode 7.3 Sigabrt error while connecting to Parse

Tags: mongodb, heroku, parse-platform, swift2, sigabrt

I have a Parse database connected to Heroku and MongoDb and I have imported the frameworks I downloaded from the Parse website. When I try to connect the app to the database in AppDelegate i get a Sigabrt error. It is in the server configuration lines because by deleting them the error disappears. I attach the image. Please help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tSj3.png)

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import Bolts
```

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

```
var window: UIWindow?


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    let configuration = ParseClientConfiguration {

        $0.applicationId = "0MBKN7pU5oSQ9kmBCL18PqSkdz1eAnIW39Gr4V1v"
        $0.server = "http://teamconnectgrego.herokuapp.com/parse"

    }


    Parse.initializeWithConfiguration(configuration)


    return true
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add your code (as text, not as image).

Comment: @EricD done i have added the code

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem. The iOS idk needed a clientKey so i added in the configuration process the`$0.clientKey = "1234567890"`and this way the error disappeared. Also in Heroku i added a config variable called clientKey and i assigned it the value 1234567890.

Answer (score 0):

The `$0.clientKey` variable is required. This is the "Master Key" when deploying a parse server.